# "Invalid character in entity name" after upgrading to {N} 6.3 with && in condition

Tags: xml, webpack, nativescript

I have two places in my app with compound conditions, such as,

```
visibility="{{ !useAlt && usingNetControl ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"
```

This works as expected, but after upgrading to {N} 6.3 I now get build warnings such as:

```
WARNING in ./views/help-page.xml
Module Warning (from ../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/xml-namespace-loader.js):
Invalid character in entity name
Line: 19
Column: 134
Char: &
 @ . sync (page|fragment)\.(xml|css|js|ts|scss|less|sass)$ ./views/help-page.xml
 @ ./bundle-config.js
 @ ./app.js
```

So it seems there's now stricter parsing by webpack, but how do I turn that off? Or rather, how should this scenario be addressed? This is a standard javascript project.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with Playground or perhaps share a sample project. I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` cannot appear in XML other than as a part of a character entity reference, within a comment, or within a CDATA section.   **Use `&amp;` instead.**

See also [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/290085)

Comment: I've confirmed that `&amp;` will work as expected in the View.  Alternatively, you can set a value in your ViewModel to `!useAlt && usingNetControl` and then test for that in your View so as to not have the `&&` in your XML.

Comment: I've also confirmed that &amp;&amp; will work as expected.  I'll mark @kjhughes response as there accepted answer. Thanks!